# Como hago este problema en python? es sobre listas y funciones

Tags: python

Tengo este problema:

```
#Crear una lista con 6 nombres ingresados por el usuario.  
#Posteriormente determinar: 
#Cuantos nombres comienzan con vocal
#Cuantos de esos nombres son de más de 5 caracteres
#(este resultado debe generarlo una función)

lista=[]
for i in range(6):
    lista.append(input("Ingrese un nombre:"))
for i in lista:
    contador=[0]
    if i[0]=="A,a" or i== "E,e" or i=="I,i" or i=="O,o" or "U,u":
       continue
       else:
       break
contador+= 1
print("nombres que cominzan con la vocal:",i)
```

intenté hacerlo pero no me resulta...

Answer (score 2):

El primero de tus errores es al hacer el `if` estas comparando la primera letra, por ejemplo `"A"` es igual que `"A,a"` y nunca será verdadero esto si deseas hacer una comparación así, se hace por separado `if i[0] == "A" or i[0]=="a"`. pero para evitar esto podemos convertir el texto en minúsculas y luego comparar con solo la minúscula.

Tu segundo error esta al momento de incrementar la variable, pues lo haces despues que acabó el bucle, por lo que siempre dará 1. Tendrás que sumar 1 si se cumple el primer `if`

```py
lista=[]
for i in range(6):
    lista.append(input("Ingrese un nombre:").lower()) #convertimos a minusculas

contador = 0 #declaramos a fuera el contador de lo contrario se reinicia para cada elemento

for i in lista:
    if i[0]=="a" or i[0]== "E" or i[0]=="i" or i[0]=="o" or i[0]=="u":
       contador+ = 1
     # eliminamos el else: break pues eso parará el ciclo por completo
       
print("nombres que cominzan con la vocal:",i)
```

Si no quieres escribir tanto en el `if` puedes crear una lista que contenga las vocales y luego comprobar si la primera letra se encuentra en la lista, eso usando la palabra reservada `in`.

```py
lista=[]
vocales = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
for i in range(6):
    lista.append(input("Ingrese un nombre:").lower()) #convertimos a minusculas

contador = 0 #declaramos a fuera el contador de lo contrario se reinicia para cada elemento

for i in lista:
    if i[0] in vocales:
       contador+ = 1
     # eliminamos el else: break pues eso parará el ciclo por completo
       
print("nombres que cominzan con la vocal:",i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ojala y esto te ayude:

```py
def dameDatos(nombre):
    primer_letra=(nombre[0]).lower()
    cantidad=len(nombre)
    print (f"nombre ingresado {nombre} primer letra {primer_letra} cantidad {cantidad}")

for i in range(6):
    n= input("Ingresa el nombre")
    dameDatos(n)
```

Salida:

```
nombre ingresado Naida primer letra n
nombre ingresado Alberto primer letra a
nombre ingresado Jose primer letra j
nombre ingresado Moises primer letra m
nombre ingresado Betovaz primer letra b
nombre ingresado Cristian primer letra c
```

Comment: corregido, gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

```
def contar(lista):
    vocales = len([x for x in lista if x[0].lower() in 'aeiou'])
    largos = len([x for x in lista if len(x) > 5])
    return vocales, largo
```

La función `contar` recibe una lista de nombres y devuelve una tupla con el número de nombre que comienzan con vocal y el el número de nombres con largo mayor a cinco. En Python una función puede retornar más de un valor (formalmente, retorna una tupla de valores).

Para contar las vocales se usa comprensión de listas con selección

```
    vocales = len([x for x in lista if x[0].lower() in 'aeiou'])
```

Simplemente recorremos la lista original seleccionando los nombres que comienzan con vocal. Luego aplicamos `len` sobre la lista y sabemos cuantos nombres cumplen la condición.

Igualmente para contar los nombres largos, hacemos lo mismo, pero seleccionando los nombres por su largo.

**Demo**

```
def contar(lista):
    vocales = len([x for x in lista if x[0].lower() in 'aeiou'])
    largos = len([x for x in lista if len(x) > 5])
    return vocales, largos


lista=[]
for i in range(6):
    lista.append(input("Ingrese un nombre:"))
vocales, largo = contar(lista)
print("nombres que cominzan con la vocal:", vocales)
print("nombres más largos que cinco letras:", largo)
```

produce:

```
Ingrese un nombre:Andres
Ingrese un nombre:Enrique
Ingrese un nombre:Gutierrez
Ingrese un nombre:Alejandria
Ingrese un nombre:Omar
Ingrese un nombre:Raulito
nombres que cominzan con la vocal: 4
nombres más largos que cinco letras: 5

Process finished with exit code 0
```